# Adding an object to useState in react. Error "Too many re-renders"

Tags: reactjs

As soon as I add an object to "setTitle" I get an error. Setting the object in "useState()" works.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState({});
  setTitle({
    "somthing": "dfgsf"
  });
  return <p>df</p>;
}
```

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an
> infinite loop.

Live: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hook-playground-bzt6s?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It's running everytime you re-render, causing another re-render and so on.  Put it in a useEffect or some other function.

Comment: You are calling `setTitle` directly in your component which means that it will be called on every render, and updating state will cause a re-render, which will result in the infinite loop. Do you want to call `setTitle` as a response to some event, or do you just want to give the title a default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When component will mount for the first time, "**setTitle**" function will be called which will update the state.

When state updates, re-rendering happens, thus "**setTitle**" function will be called again, triggering an infinite loop

**Solution:**

Use "**useffect**" or some **other function** to update the state

Answer (score 1):

You must use initialState when defining the state. You can then add an `onClick`in order to change the title state using `setState`

This is the right way:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState({"somthing": "dfgsf"});

  function buttonHandler() {
    setTitle({
        "somthing": "dfgsf"
      });
      console.log(title)
  }
  return <button onClick={buttonHandler}>sdf</button>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because state updates cause a re-render. Because you're updating the state **unconditionally** the component keeps re-rendering indefinitely.
This doesn't have anything to do with initial state.

Answer (score 0):

useState takes an initialState as it's argument.

Try something like this?

```
export default function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("My Initial Title");
  return <p onClick={() => setTitle('New')}>{title}</p>;
}
```